# LaTeX - using \hyperref to refer to a section/subsection before the section/subsection is defined?

Tags: pdf, latex, reference, hyperlink, pdflatex

I have been using the hyperref package and `\hyperref[…]{…}` to put a clickable link (in a PDF) to a section or subsection. However I want to put the clickable link before i put the `\subsection` declaration. My first attempt seems to produce a link that goes to the first page. Is there something special you have to do to get the links working before you define them? I am already running latex twice on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was a bug in my code. I had extra trailing whitespace around the `\hyperref` call, which means it wasn't the same text. If I remove the spaces, and run pdflatex twice, then everything works